# How do I set a permission in Bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I have a Minecraft plugin called JustExplode, and I'm trying to make it so that if someone has the permission justexplode.timer, they have to wait 10 minutes before they can use the command /explode again. It doesn't work, I have tried multiple ways, and I'm new to programming....can someone help me? Here is my main class JustExplode.java:

```
package me.sam1370.justexplode;

import java.util.Date;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class JustExplode extends JavaPlugin{


@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getLogger().info("JustExplode has been enabled!");
    getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    saveConfig();
}
@Override
public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("JustExplode has been disabled!");
}


@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("explode") && sender.hasPermission("justexplode.explode")){
            // Make sure that the player specified exactly one argument (the name of the player to exPLODE!).
            if (args.length != 1) {
            // When onCommand() returns false, the help message associated with that command is displayed.
            return false;
        }

        // Make sure the sender is a player.
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Only players can explode other players.");
            return true;
        }

        // Get the player who should be exploded. Remember that indices start with 0, not 1.
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        // Make sure the player is online.
        if (target == null) {
            sender.sendMessage(args[0] + " is not currently online.");
            return true;
        }


        Location loc = target.getLocation();
        target.getWorld().spawnEntity(loc, EntityType.PRIMED_TNT);
        String actuality = target.getName();
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            Player player = (Player) sender;

            String localMessage = getConfig().getString("message");

            if(localMessage.contains("%player%")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("%player%", actuality);
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&4")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&4", ChatColor.DARK_RED + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&c")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&c", ChatColor.RED + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&6")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&6", ChatColor.GOLD + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&e")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&e", ChatColor.YELLOW + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&2")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&2", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&a")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&a", ChatColor.GREEN + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&b")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&b", ChatColor.AQUA + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&3")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&3", ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&1")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&1", ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&9")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&9", ChatColor.BLUE + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&d")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&d", ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&5")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&5", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&f")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&f", ChatColor.WHITE + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&7")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&7", ChatColor.GRAY + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&l")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&l", ChatColor.BOLD + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&n")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&n", ChatColor.UNDERLINE + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&o")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&o", ChatColor.ITALIC + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&k")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&k", ChatColor.MAGIC + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&m")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&m", ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "");
            }

            if(localMessage.contains("&r")) { 
                localMessage = localMessage.replace("&r", ChatColor.RESET + "");
            }


            player.sendMessage(localMessage);

        return true;
    }else{
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permission to explode anyone!");
        return true;
    }



}
        return true;

}
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onCommand1(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("explode") && sender.hasPermission("justexplode.timer")){

            long timerMinutes = getConfig().getLong("timerMinutes");


            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = 0L;

            while (elapsedTime < timerMinutes) {

                long timeLeft = timerMinutes - elapsedTime;

                String localMessage2 = getConfig().getString("timer");

                String timeLeftString = Long.toString(timeLeft);

                if(localMessage2.contains("%timeleft%")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("%timeleft%", timeLeftString);
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&4")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&4", ChatColor.DARK_RED + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&c")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&c", ChatColor.RED + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&6")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&6", ChatColor.GOLD + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&e")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&e", ChatColor.YELLOW + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&2")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&2", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&a")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&a", ChatColor.GREEN + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&b")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&b", ChatColor.AQUA + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&3")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&3", ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&1")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&1", ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&9")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&9", ChatColor.BLUE + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&d")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&d", ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&5")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&5", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&f")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&f", ChatColor.WHITE + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&7")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&7", ChatColor.GRAY + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&l")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&l", ChatColor.BOLD + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&n")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&n", ChatColor.UNDERLINE + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&o")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&o", ChatColor.ITALIC + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&k")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&k", ChatColor.MAGIC + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&m")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&m", ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "");
                }

                if(localMessage2.contains("&r")) { 
                    localMessage2 = localMessage2.replace("&r", ChatColor.RESET + "");
                }


                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    Player player = (Player) sender;


                    player.sendMessage(localMessage2);

                elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
            }



        }
        return true;

}
        return true;

}
}
```

And here is my config.yml that I set up:

```
# Default config file for JustExplode, by Sam1370
# There isn't a reload config command for right now, just reload or restart the server

# Change this to the message you want to see when you are exploding a player
# Put %player% in it to get the player that you are exploding
# Color codes are now supported, as opposed to version 1.0.8.2. YES!!!
message: "&aExploded &c%player%!"

# Change this to the message you want to see when a player tries to do /explode with the permission justexplode.timer
# Put %timeleft% in it to get the time left before they can explode again
# Color codes are supported

timer: "You can't explode anyone for %timeleft%!"

# Specify how many minutes, in milliseconds, how long you want someone to wait before they can do /explode again
# The default is 600000 milliseconds, which is 10 minutes
timerMinutes: 600000
```

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these types of delays you need to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`and a simple `HashMap`

## How?

It's actually pretty easy, let me show you an example i wrote few weeks ago.

```
private static HashMap<CommandSender, Long> lastExplodeUses = new HashMap<>();

public static HashMap<CommandSender, Long> getLastExplodeUses() {
    return lastExplodeUses;
}

public static void setLastExplodeUse(CommandSender player, long till) {
    lastHelpopSended.put(player, till);
}

public static boolean canExplode(CommandSender player) {
    long timeExploded = lastExplodeUses.get(player) == null ? 0 : lastExplodeUses.get(player);
    if (timeExploded == 0) return true; // if it's 0 - you can execute explode command.
    long timeCurrent = System.currentTimeMillis(); // current time in millis
    if (timeExploded < timeCurrent) { // if the timeExploded is lower than timeCurrent you can execude explode command.
        return true;
    }
    return false; // if not, you cant.
}
```

What next? You need to add to your command a few functions.

```
if (sender.hasPermission("justexplode.timer")) { // if player has permission, if not - bypass the timer.
    if (!canExplode(sender)) {
        // you can't explode yet :/
        return;
    }
    setLastExplodeUse(sender, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000); // set the till time to explode use. Current time + 10000, 10000 = 10 seconds.
}
// there you can do your explosion etc.
```

***Remember!*** If you're creating for example `kits` when the delays are about `24 hours` long, you need to save that `HashMap` to `MySQL` or somewhere else and load on start!

Comment: Hey, where do I put the "few functions" code? I tried putting it after the first example code that you provided, but it kept saying "unreachable code". Where do I put it?

Comment: is `return;` supposed to be true or false?

Comment: @Sam1370 oh sorry, I created own command executor so I have void method. You need to put `true` :)

Comment: @Sam1370 If I resolve your problem, make sure you hit checkmark button! :P

Comment: I suggest you:
1: Use UUID instead of player instance.
2: Remove player from lists after cooldown ended to get rid of memory leaks.

Comment: @Lightspeed360 1. It actually doesn't matter. 2. Sure thing, i forgot

Comment: @xVacuum If the player relogs while the cooldown is still active and in the lists it will cause more memory leaks. I suggest you use UUID whenever storing players.

Answer (score 0):

When someone executed the command /explode store the players name and the current timestamp in a map. When a user tries to execute the command again, check if the player is in the map and if the difference in time is equal ro greater than the time set in the config.yml.

Small example code:

```
Map<Player, Long> times = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
  if (!(sender instanceof Player))
    return false;

  Player player = (Player) sender;

  if (times.contains(player) && times.get(player) >= delay) {
    //execute command
    times.put(player, System.currentTimeMillis());
  } else if (!times.contains(player)) {
    //execute command
    times.put(player, System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
}
```

Comment: Um...how? I'm new to programming and Java, so I don't know how to do it...sorry for bothering you